# Want rsync to list copied/deleted files

Tags: rsync

I would like rsync to output the list of files which it actually copied, respectively deleted. From the man page, I though the following command will do:

```
rsync -a --info=backup2,copy2,del2 SOURCEDIR DESTDIR
```

By looking at DESTDIR afterwards, I see that the files are updated, but I don't get any list of files from rsync. Also tried it with just `--info=backup,copy,del`, but to no avail.

Why is it that my approach doesn't work, and how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2):

Your concept of *backup* is different to that used by `rsync`. In `rsync` a backup is a copy on the destination of the original file before it was updated by `rsync`. Your command doesn't create any backups, so none will be listed.

Similarly, your concept of *copy* is different to that used by `rsync`. There are no copies made, so none will be listed.

This will get you a list of the *files* transferred or deleted, but note that neither your command nor this specifies that files are to be deleted (`--delete`), so the `del` is actually a no-op.

```
rsync -a --info=name,del SOURCEDIR/ DESTDIR | grep -v '/$'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As for the `--delete`, I missed to write it in my post when I simplified for the purpose of this posting the (pretty complex) rsync command. I'm surprised to learn that there is a difference between *copying* and *transfering* files!

Comment: @user1934438 copying is when there is already an instance of the file on the target, in a parallel directory. The file can be copied from there instead of transferred across from the source.

Comment: Absolute excellent explanation! I have been searching for one hour how to get "just" the list of transferred files.. :-( and it seems that the `grep` command is not something you can avoid.. (because of timestamp changes or something like that). It's really not easy to understand their vocabulary and to do something that seems fairly common to wish :-). Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopheMuller thanks. I'm pleased this answer helped you.